# Vertical centering a div with percentage based images

Tags: jquery, css, html, percentage, centering

I'm currently programming my new web portfolio. So far so good. I decided to make it completely %-based and I'm struggeling with one last detail:

I have to center %-based images vertically in a div box which is also %-based.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PX4tF/4/

This is the code that doesn't work like I want it to be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

         $(window).resize(function(){

          $('.vertical_center').css({
           position:'relative',
           left: ($(window).width() 
             - $('.vertical_center').outerWidth())/2,
           top: ($(window).height() 
             - $('.vertical_center').outerHeight())/2
          });

         });

         // To initially run the function:
         $(window).resize();

        });
```

The script I currently use only starts to work correctly when I resize the window. Before that it kind of centers the image but not correctly. Also I have multiple div boxes like the one in fiddle on my page and currently I have to duplicate the script to center it correctly after the browser is resiszed. Is there a way to make that easier?

Here is the link to the beta site: http://www.zeiteffekt.de/relaunch

I'm not that programming guy so I hope you guys can help me with this.

Cheers,
Tim

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
function alignImage()
{
    $('.vertical_center').css({
        position:'relative',
        left: ($(window).width() - $('.vertical_center').outerWidth())/2,
        top: ($(window).height() - $('.vertical_center').outerHeight())/2
    });
}
$(window).load(function() {
    alignImage();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    alignImage();
});
```

Images is not ready when $(document).ready is called. Use load instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
        $( ".img-swap").each(function() {
            $(this).css({
               position:'relative',
               marginTop: ($(this).parent().outerHeight() 
                - ($(this).outerHeight()+15))/2
             });
         });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vusan/PX4tF/6/)
I replace `marginTop` instead of `top` Because `marginTop` will help to push the text just below the image while `top` push image only.

Comment: does this also work before resizing the window like in the example of @TommySorensen? If yes it's perfect.